# SQOOP export - Issues with UPSERT

Tags: sqoop

Through SQOOP, I am trying to export a file from HDFS to Postgres DB(version 9.4). While doing so, UPSERT is not working. Only insert or update through SQOOP is working but not UPSERT(using allowinsert command). Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1):

UPSERT is only supported for Oracle, also for MySQL after Version 1.4.3.
[See description of this JIRA issue.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-621)